# How to get a value from radio button with xml data file?

Tags: html

I tried to get a value from radio button on JS, but unfortunately no idea...
I want to give a grade score, if the value are matched each other When comparing the presented value with the checked value. 
But this code doesn't run I hope it. What can I fix?? Already I searched a google, but still struggling too much time. Please help me. Thanks.

Sorry I deleted my code because the code is whole wrong.

Comment: It's not  clear where you want to get the value of a radio button in your code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  I modified the code to be a clear as your mentioned. Just I wrote a data of a xml file simply. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the below snippet of code.

```
    function processXML(xhr) {
        let i;
        let xmldoc = xhr.responseXML;
        let display = "";
        let gradeCount = 0;
        let totalGrade = 0;
        let x = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("question");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            display += "<br>" + "<b>Question</b>" + " " + "<b>";
            display += x[i].getElementsByTagName("qnumber")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>" + "<br>";
            display += x[i].getElementsByTagName("qtitle")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</b>" + "<br>" + "<br>";
            if (i === 0) {
                display += "&nbsp&nbsp" + "<input class='radioSolution' type='radio' name='listAnswer' value='a' data-questionid='i'>" + "&nbsp&nbsp";
                display += "&nbsp&nbsp" + "A) " + x[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
                display += "&nbsp&nbsp" + "<input class='radioSolution' type='radio' name='listAnswer' value='b' data-questionid='i'>" + "&nbsp&nbsp";
                display += "&nbsp&nbsp" + "B) " + x[i].getElementsByTagName("b")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
                display += "&nbsp&nbsp" + "<input class='radioSolution' type='radio' name='listAnswer' value='c' data-questionid='i'>" + "&nbsp&nbsp";
                display += "&nbsp&nbsp" + "C) " + x[i].getElementsByTagName("c")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
                display += "&nbsp&nbsp" + "<input class='radioSolution' type='radio' name='listAnswer' value='d' data-questionid='i'>" + "&nbsp&nbsp";
                display += "&nbsp&nbsp" + "D) " + x[i].getElementsByTagName("d")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>" + "<br>";
            }

       document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = display;
    }
}

function getSolution() {
```

var radioButtons = document.getElementsByClassName(".radioSolution");
for(var i=0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
        var currentElement = radioButtons[i];
        if(currentElement.checked) {
            var questionId = currentElement.getAttribute('data-questionid');
          var selectedAnswer = currentElement.value(); //This gives the value as "on", instead of reading from value, better use a data-* attribute and use the code above this line for getting the selected value.
          //Now you have the QuestionId and the answer, you can proceed further
        }

```
}
```

**Note**
The above code uses data-* attributes to set the question id so that in case you are reading the values during a form submit, you can get all the solutions in a single shot.

Also, we are using the class names for ease in reading the elements from the dom.

The `getSolution()` method will process the elements from the DOM and give the question and its answer so that you can start processing further.

HTH

Comment: Thank you so much, but I don't understand JQuery lang. I am a student and only learned JS :( .

Comment: @JayXD, I have changed the code to use vanilla javascript, if any minor issues, you can handle and fix 'em i guess.